# expression tree evaluation java.lang.NumberFormatException java

Tags: java, expression-trees

I've created an expression tree with three classes (one for the structure of the tree which evaluates the expression and also gives the postfix and infix notation of it(Expr), the other one just builds the tree from the expression(using stack ...) and the other one is EvalExpr which is my main)
but I get an error for the expression "( 2 + 3.5 )" that I don't know where it come from. an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.5"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at exprTree.Expr.eval(Expr.java:68)
    at exprTree.Expr.eval(Expr.java:74)
    at exprTree.Expr.eval(Expr.java:73)
    at exprTree.Expr.eval(Expr.java:73)
    at EvalExpr.main(EvalExpr.java:42)
```

and my method eval() is like this:

```
public double eval() 
    {
        double leftOperand = 0;
        double rightOperand = 0;
        String operator;

        if(this == null)
            return 0;

        else if(rightChild == null && leftChild == null)
            return Double.parseDouble(value); 

        else 
        {
            operator = value;
            leftOperand = leftChild.eval();
            rightOperand = rightChild.eval();
            return calc(operator, leftOperand, rightOperand);
        }
    }
```

can anyone help me to find this mysterious error?
thanks

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly throw this exception, as it doesn't call `Integer.parseInt()`. Ergo either the exception isn't being thrown or this isn't the code that threw it. Not a real question.

Comment: this is exactly my code

Answer (score 1):

Some code (that you are not showing) is trying to parse "3.5" into an int, which won't work.

```
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at exprTree.Expr.eval(Expr.java:68)
```

Take a look at Expr.java, line 68.

If the above code (which has Double.parseDouble instead) is what you think you are running, try to re-compile everything.

I'd also consider using BigDecimal, which avoids nasty floating point precision problems that Double may cause you.